# Integral Domain and Degree of Polynomials in $R[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

In an algebra book there is the following proposition: Given the polynomial ring $R[X]$ in one variable over the ring $R$, then for polynomials $f,g \in R[X]$ it follows: $$\deg(f+g)\leq \max(\deg f, \deg g) $$ $$ \deg (f\cdot g)\leq \deg f +\deg g.$$ Moreover, in the case **$R$ is integral**, it follows: $$\deg (f \cdot g)= \deg f +\deg g.$$

In the same page it is presented the divison with rest in the polynomial ring $R[X]:$ Let $g\in R[X]$, whose largest coefficient $a_d$ is a unity in $R.$ Then for every $f\in R[X]$ there exist unique polynomials $q,r \in R[X]$ with $$ f=qg + r, \,\,\,\,\deg r< d.$$

In the proof of the latter statement one reads: $\deg (qg)= g\deg q + \deg g$ for polynomials $q\in R[X],$ even if **$R$ is not integral**. Here is the point which makes the trouble. It looks like a contradiction because in the former statement it was said the contrary, i.e. the equality holds only if $R$ is integrable. Cany somebody shed some light on this, explaining what i am missing here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The former statement did not say "the equality holds only if $R$ is integrable".

What the former statement *did* say is "the equality holds if $R$ is integrable".

Also, "integrable" is very unusual terminology; I think you are referring to what we usually call "integral".

---

Assuming that you do mean "integral", then the following is true:

> The identity $\deg(fg) =\deg(f) + \deg(g)$ holds for *every* *every* pair of polynomials $f,g$ only if $R$ is integral.

So, if $R$ is not integrable the identity has to fail for *some* polynomials. But only for *some*. It can hold for other polynomials.

For example, in *any* polynomial ring,

$$\deg(x^5) = 5 = 3 + 2 = \deg(x^3) + \deg(x^2)$$

---

The proof of this statement is simple, simply by looking at the leading coefficients:

$$ (f_d x^d + f_{d-1} x^{d-1} + \cdots) \cdot (g_e x^e + g_{e-1} x^{e-1} + \cdots ) = f_d g_e x^{d+e} + \cdots $$

Assuming $f_d \neq 0$ and $g_e \neq 0$, we see that

$$\deg(fg) = d + e = \deg(f) + \deg(g)$$

if and only if $f_d g_e \neq 0$. Thus any failure of this identity implies the existence of a pair of zero divisors, and any pair of zero divisors allows you to construct counterexamples.

Comment: Many thanks. In the book the statement says: ''It is always $\mathrm{grad}(fg) = \mathrm{grad}(f) + \mathrm{grad}(g)$ for polynomials $q\in R[X],$ even if $R$ were not integral.'' If this fails for some polynomials, as you say, then the statement must also fail. So the word ''always'' provokes the trouble. Can you give a further comment and give an example of a non integral ring $R$, so that for some polynomials the statement fails ?

Comment: @user249018: If the book said that somewhere, it's wrong. However, that's not the statement you were asking about in the OP, which is of the form "... *there exists a $q$* such that ..."; so that $q,g$ are among those *some* polynomials satisfying that grading identity.

Comment: The statment remains unchanged, I only precised very wordly the commencement of the proof, which is: Let us note that, it is always $\mathrm{grad}(fg) = \mathrm{grad}(f) + \mathrm{grad}(g)$, even in the case  $R$ is not integral.

Comment: @user249018: The reproduced statement is not about arbitrary $f$ and $g$, it is about the $q$ and $g$ appearing in the theorem. $g$ is restricted to a subclass of polynomials, and $q$ is only existentially quantified. (in fact, $g$ is restricted to the class of polynomials for which this grade identity is *always* satisfied no matter which other polynomial it is paired with. But again, only *some* polynomials have this property if the ring is not integral)